# SSIS: combining fields from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have two source tables regarding members of staff: Recruitment and Training. I need to combine them into a single table.

```
Recruitment table: [UniqueID], [SupplierName], RecruitmentDate, RecruitmentField1, RecruitmentField2, RecruitmentField3, Comments

Training table: [UniqueID], [Supplier], TrainingDate, TrainingField1, TrainingField2, TrainingField 3, TrainingField4, TrainingField5, Comments.
```

I want to end up with one table (called SupplyRecruitment) containing the following fields - `using [UniqueID] AND [Supplier] as a join key` (individuals can exist to more than one supplier, so need to join on unique record based on UniqueID and Supplier).

```
UniqueID, 
SupplierName, 
RecruitmentDate, 
RecruitmentField1, 
RecruitmentField2, 
RecruitmentField3, 
RecruitmentComments, 
TrainingDate, 
TrainingField1, 
TrainingField2, 
TrainingField3, 
TrainingField4, 
TrainingField5, 
TrainingComments.
```

The datasets are not very large (maximum 12,000 rows) so performance is not a huge focus. Simplicity and accuracy is key.

Looking for a solution based on SSIS tasks (using SQL 2012). If this is not possible, then some help on SQL logic would be appreciated. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the advantage of doing this in SSIS would be to be honest.

```
select r.UniqueID
    , r.SupplierName
    , r.RecruitmentDate
    , r.RecruitmentField1
    , r.RecruitmentField2
    , r.RecruitmentField3
    , r.RecruitmentComments
    , t.TrainingDate
    , t.TrainingField1
    , t.TrainingField2
    , t.TrainingField3
    , t.TrainingField4
    , t.TrainingField5
    , t.TrainingComments
from dbo.Recruitment r 
      inner join do.Training t on r.UniqueID = t.UniqueID
                                  and r.SupplierName = t.Supplier
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add OLE Source component for Recruitment
2. Add OLE Source component for Training
3. Add one Sort component for each and sort by uniqueid/supplier
4. Add merge join an merge using  uniqueid/supplier as keys
5. Select the required fields in the merge join
6. Direct the output of the merge join to an OLE Destination component

Comment: Thank you. Using your approach: How do I direct the Comments from the Recruitment table to the RecruitmentComments field in the new table, and direct the Comments from the Training table to the TrainingComments field? They both come up as "Comments" in the Merge  Join editor and I cannot distinguish between the two different fields. I'm guessing a Derived Column between the Sort and Merge join component would work?

Comment: within merge join you have 'output alias' that you can use to reference the columns by an alias. By default if two columns have same name, one of them will have a "(1)" added as an alias.